# UIScrollView not showing scroll indicator

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which I create and size dynamically using...

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width , length);
```

I then add `subviews` to the `UIScrollView`.
I do have `scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;`

When scrolling the scroll indicator never appears.

Even if I call `[scrollView flashScrollIndicators]` nothing happens.

Ideas?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Sure you aren't setting it somewhere else back to NO?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Had the same problem and couldn't find the cause. The last answer gave the final hint: whenever I added new subviews I first removed all existing subviews from the scrollview (and apparently also the scroll indicators).

After checking in my loop, if the subview really was of the kind I wanted to be removed the scroll indicators showed up:

```
for (NSObject * subview in [[[scrollView subviews] copy] autorelease]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[MySubView class]]) {
       [(MySubView*)subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Update: changed code to Nikolai's suggestion

Comment: There's a subtle bug in this code: UIView's `subviews` method returns the original array of subviews used by the view. This means the above code mutates the array while iterating over it. Easy fix: iterate over `[[[scrollView subviews] copy] autorelease]`

Comment: Why do you need to do copy and autorelease? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, after checking for the type of the subview i was removing it worked fine, ty ty ty. :)

Comment: I am using UIImageView as subview, it seems the scroll indicator is also kind of UIImageView.

Comment: Exact same issue as @chancyWu, I add `UIImageView` and remove them first. This still removes the scroll indicator. Fixed it by just skipping 1st subview.

Answer (score 14):

When I've dealt with this before, in my implementation of a grid, I would occasionally get some cells over the top of the scroll indicator. To fix this I am now inserting subviews at index 0 rather than adding them, which adds them to the top. So try something like this:

`[scrollview insertSubview:subview atIndex:0];`

Comment: Any chance of a similar solution for a `UICollectionView`?

Comment: In my case, the similar problem was solved by adding higher zIndex to scrollView layer -> `self.scrollView.layer.zPosition = 1000;`

Answer (score 11):

For me, the horizontal indicator had mysteriously disappeared in my app on iOS 7. Later found out that for some strange reason, I had to enable both `Shows Horizontal Indicator` and `Shows Vertical Indicator` to make the horizontal one show up. If I set it to not show the vertical indicator, it would also not show horizontal indicator.

[image]

Comment: Sigh .. first world iOS7 problems. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 9):

I fix this by adding this code after add new subview:

```
self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
```

Comment: This and the content covering my indicators was the root of the problem I ran into.

Answer (score 2):

It will also happen (at least in the case of a UITableView) if the contentSize is too small for the table view to scroll. If you have enabled bouncing, then the tableview does not actually scroll and does not display the indicators therefore. Try fitting more content inside.

Comment: This was it for me—thank you!  I'd gotten confused as to why the scroll indicator was showing up when my view controller was presented with `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` but not with `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`… turns out that difference in height was just enough to determine whether my content all fit onscreen! 

Answer (score 2):

It can happen also if the parent of the scrollview is **smaller horizontally** than the scroll view itself :

The scroll bar is stuck to the right side of the `ScrollView` / `TableView` and this right side is not visible due to the parent bounds ( with a **clipToBounds** hidding it for instance).

I've seen this issue so I share it in case it can help.

Just check the width of your `ScrollView`'s frame not to be bigger than the width of its parent view frame.

Answer (score 1):

Two conditions,

1. If you are using a storyboard
2. If you are using a UITableView inside a UIViewController

Then, you should check your indicator insets are set to 0 (or any other number that is relevant to your autolayout):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this when the UIScrollView was a 48 px tall horizontal band, scrollable horizontally. Maybe Cocoa decides the area is too small for a scroll indicator...

Comment: In this case the scrollview is several times the length of the screen and exactly the width of the screen.