# Why is my UIScrollView horizontal scroll bar not showing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
    CGFloat width = textField.text.floatValue;
    CGFloat height = textField2.text.floatValue;
    CanvasView *canv = [[CanvasView alloc]     initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.myscrollview.frame.size.width - width)/2, (self.myscrollview.frame.size.height - height)/2, width, height)];
    [canv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.canvas = canv;
    [self.myscrollview addSubview:canv];
```

I am using this code to add a `UIView` at runtime in a `UIScrollView` and the `width` and `height` parameter are taken from the user at **runtime** but the problem is:
if the `width` and `height` is more than the size of `UIScrollView` then it is not showing horizontal scroll bar.

Why is this?

Comment: hi, please assign the value for scroll view property "showsHorizontalScrollIndicator" to YES. it will help you.
self.myscrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

Comment: Pretty sure @Puneet has got this one correct.  Please post the code where you set contentSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie with the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`.

When `width` and `height` increases than you must change `contentSize` of `UIScrollView` accordingly.

It is `contentSize` that defines the limits of scrollable content that is to be shown on `scrollview`.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

If in your `scrollview` you have only `UIView` then the above line of code must work in any case. 
Otherwise you need to set contentSize accordingly to include other `UIComponents` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `self.myscrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES`

Good luck!

Comment: One possibility would be to re-add all the scroll view's subviews to the scrollview once you add a new subview. I'm not sure that it will work (because I've never tried this), but I read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017858/uiscrollview-not-showing-scroll-indicator) and it may work out for you. Please let me know if that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set scrollview frame as your desire screen size(that is visible area).
only you set scroll view content size.

```
CGFloat width = textField.text.floatValue;
CGFloat height = textField2.text.floatValue;
self.myscrollview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
CGSizeMake contentOffset;
contentOffset = CGSizeMake(width, height);
[self.myscrollview. setContentSize:contentOffset animated:NO];


CanvasView *canv = [[CanvasView alloc]     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
[canv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.canvas = canv;
[self.myscrollview addSubview:canv];
```

then if you want scroll indicator you can use

```
self.myscrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
```

Comment: after adding this snippet it is not showing me the canvas added

Comment: hey check your canvas frame is differ form content size... NSLog your frame and content size

Comment: i print the size of frame it is showing width=768 and height=1004 and then i am setting the size of scrollview same as that of frame, then in the width and height parameter i am passing width=2000 and height=200 but still scrollview is not showing scrolling

Comment: hey scroll view size must 768X1004 in that set content size of the scroll view as you passed values. use above code for that..

Comment: the above code is not working, it not showing the canvas added

Comment: see i am setting the canvas in the middle of the scrollview if it has dimensions less than scrollview, this is adding the canvasview to the scrollview but still not able to scroll :(