# Ios 8 scroll indicator is not showing in scroll view

Tags: ios, swift

I am using scroll view, but scroll indicator is not working. I am setting inset to bottom but scroll indicator is still not showing.

Here screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why scroll indicator is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Is your UIScrollView going off screen? Are you using AutoLayout? Try calling `flashScrollIndicators()` in your `viewDidAppear()`. This question has already been asked - [UIScrollView not showing scroll indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017858/uiscrollview-not-showing-scroll-indicator)

Comment: I mean I can't scroll. I am using auto layout.